# Problemas al direccionar con jQuery, la variable llega sin valor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia compañeros, estoy realizandi un programa web y tengo un problema al enviar  una variable por medio de jquery y javascript.

tengo el siguiente metodo que redirecciona y manda una variable por esta direccion:

```js
function consultarPaciente(){
    url = "index.php?accion=consultarPaciente&documento="+$("#asignarDocumento").attr('value');
    $("#paciente").load(url);
   /* alert($("#asignarDocumento").attr('value'));*/
}
```

el codigo que tengo comentado lo hago para saber que valor me llega en la ejecucion el cual indica que es indefinido.

El html que utiliza dicho codigo es el siguiente:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
        <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="encabezado">
                <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="contenido">
                <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
                <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Como se puede ver consulto primero si esta el paciente y lo hago con la funcion de javascript.

```js
<tr>
  <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
      <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar"      id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
  </td>
</tr>
```

la funcion en javascript me redirecciona a la pagina principal llamada index.php que ejecuta funciones en la clase Controlador y GestorCita.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once 'Controlador/Controlador.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/GestorCita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Cita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Paciente.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Conexion.php';

    $controlador = new Controlador();

    if(isset($_GET['accion'])){

        if($_GET['accion'] == 'asignar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/asignar.php');
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/consultar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelar') {
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/cancelar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'guardarCita') {
           $controlador->agregarCita($_POST['asignarDocumento'], $_POST['medico'],
                   $_POST['fecha'], $_POST['hora'], $_POST['consultorio']); 
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarCita'){
            $controlador->consultarCitas($_POST['consultarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelarCita') {
            $controlador->cancelarCita($_POST['cancelarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarPaciente') {
            $controlador->consultarPaciente($_GET['documento']);
        }
        else{
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
        }
    }
    else{
        $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

Aqui esta el metodo consultarPaciente en la clase controlador la cual es instanciada en el index.php.

```
    #metodo consultar paciente
public function consultarPaciente($doc) {
    $gestorCita = new GestorCita();
    $result = $gestorCita->consultarPaciente($doc);
    require_once 'Vista/html/consultarPaciente.php'; 
}
```

y aqui esta la clase GestorCita la cual es instanciada en la clase anterior controlador.

```
    #metodo consultar paciente
public function consultarPaciente($doc) {
    $gestorCita = new GestorCita();
    $result = $gestorCita->consultarPaciente($doc);
    require_once 'Vista/html/consultarPaciente.php'; 
}
```

Al ejecutar en el navegador ingreso un usuario que esta ingresado en la base de datos y me aparece que no esta ingresado.

[image: Interfaz de ejecucion]

.El problema que detecto es que no me esta llegando el valor 'documento' ya que al imprimirlo me aparece como indefinido.

nota: la conexion y la consulta ya las verifique y funcionan normalmente ya que tengo otras consultas y no tengo problemas.

muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda estoy empezando en esto y a de ser cualquier problema pero ya saben como es al principio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te aparece como indefinido por que estas intentando recoger el valor del atributo 
value de ese elemento y no lo tiene,por lo que para recoger el valor de ese input, debes recogerlo así:

```
$("#asignarDocumento").val()
```